# SSJS Triggered Send not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, wsproxy

I tried to strip this back as simple as possible using WSProxy to conduct the triggered send. I tested this in Cloud Pages, and I just get the loading screen when I click Publish to preview. I also tried the try catch method on the prox call, but that didn't work either.

Here's what I have so far, please note I altered the code to hide PII data.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1")
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var tsExKey = '102425'; 
var EmailAddress = 'email@example.com'; 
var SubscriberKey = 'email@example.com'; 
var deName='DE_NAME_HERE';
var audience='Segment Here';
var approverName='Approver';

var tsDef = {
    TriggeredSendDefinition: {
        CustomerKey: tsExKey
    },
    Subscribers: [{
        EmailAddress: EmailAddress,
        SubscriberKey: SubscriberKey,
        Attributes: [{
            Name: 'deName',
            Value: deName
        },{
          Name: 'audience',
          Value:audience
        },{
          Name:'approverName',
          Value:approverName
        }
        ]
    }]
};
var res = prox.createItem('TriggeredSend', tsDef);   
Write(Stringify(res)); 
</script>
```

I can't figure out what's going on here. I checked the de to ensure the spelling of the fields was correct (the Approve Date field has a default value of Current date)
[image]

Comment: It won't work on preview. You need to fully publish it for it to work on a CloudPage.

Comment: Is this specific to WS Proxy only?

Comment: No there is a lot of API/SSJS Core functions that are affected this way and will not work on Cloud Page Preview.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!